# Dynamic menu contribution in plugin.xml

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In my `plugin.xml` I have

```xml
<menuContribution
      allPopups="false"
      locationURI="menu:arm.views.funblocks?after=additions">
      <menu
           icon="icons/fblock.gif"
           id="arm.views.funblocks.create"
           label="%arm.views.funblocks.create">
           <dynamic class="ru.focusmedia.odp.arm.funblocks.navigator.admin.CreateFunBlockContrib"
               id="arm.views.funblocks.create.menuitems">
           </dynamic>
      </menu>
      <command
           commandId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.delete"
           style="push">
      </command>
</menuContribution>
```

and this works fine. However, if I replace `menu:` with `toolbar:` in `locationURI`, only the delete command shows up, but not the menu. I've also tried replacing `<menu>` element with `<toolbar>`, but with no result. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add a menu or toolbar to a toolbar.

You can make the content of a menu of toolbar completely dynamic by using the `class` attribute of the `menuContribution` element.

Comment: If I add a command with `pulldown` style (as in http://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions/Dropdown_Command), can I contribute a `dynamic` element to its menu?

Comment: Yes, that is indeed possible.

Comment: Thanks, that works for me. Even better if I get the handler to show the same menu.